# iOS app update post processing script upon install

Tags: ios, app-store, installation, post-processing

I would like to delete some files from apps temporary folder if user updates to specific version.

Is there an option to do so kind of a post processing after app is being updated and installed from `App Store`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not directly.

You have to include such a logic into your app. You could write a block that checks if the files are present in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` function using `dispatch_async` to run it on a low priority queue after your app was started.

You could also write a flag in the userdefaults after the block is done so it is only executed once after the update.

Comment: I thought there is some way of default post processing instead of handling it on your own. Ok, thanks!